# Python: nested for loop

Tags: python

Hello am a beginner to python and I have been stuck at this problem for awhile now. I want to start with 2 lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list2 = [a, b, c]
```

And write a function that will give me this output:

```
a
1
2
3
b
4
5
6
c
7
8
9
```

I have tried using nested for loops and a counter but I am unsure how to obtain the above result.

```
counter = 0
for i in list2:
    print(i)
    for j in list1:
        print(j)
        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
            counter = 0
            break
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The inner loop shouldn't iterate over "list1" but over "range(3)" as you only want three items of list1 for each item of list2. You can use the counter as index into list1 to find which item should be returned next (but don't reset it to 0 in this case).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way, closer to what you intended to write:

```
j = 0
for i in list2:
    print(i)
    for _ in range(3):
        print(list1[j])
        j += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option:

```
for i, v1 in enumerate(list2):
    print(v1)
    for v2 in list1[i*3:(i+1)*3]:
        print(v2)
```

You don't need to make and update your own counters here.  The built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function generates a counter for you and automatically updates it for each step of the loop.  Then you can use list slicing to get the right three values of the inner list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in list2:
    print(i)

    # here you don't have to take it back to 0        
    counter = 0
    for j in range(len(list1)):
        # Use range to loop the list so you can cut it off later
        # from the position you reach the third element
        print(list1[j])
        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
            list1 = list1[j + 1:]
            break
```

It outputs what you expect:

```
a
1
2
3
b
4
5
6
c
7
8
9
```